# How can I press the alert ok button programmatically?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-rc, alert

How can I press the OK button in a JS alert programmatically?

What I want to do: every time after the alert is created, the OK button is pressed.

This is for a UI test using Selenium RC.

Also, I have already checked: [Click in OK button inside an Alert (Selenium IDE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348937/click-in-ok-button-inside-an-alert-selenium-ide).

Edit: I had already used `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation()` and placed it before clicking the button the generated the alert. I also tried placing it after. Nothing worked!

Comment: Is there any reason you are still using Selenium RC? It is officially deprecated.

Comment: You can do that using `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can actually see an alert dialog, then it can't be done. Selenium should handle it for you. But, [as stated in Selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#handling-browser-popup-windows):

> Selenium tries to conceal those dialogs from you (by replacing
>   window.alert, window.confirm and window.prompt) so they won’t stop the
>   execution of your page. If you’re seeing an alert pop-up, it’s
>   probably because it fired during the page load process, which is
>   usually too early for us to protect the page.

It is a known limitation of Selenium RC (and, therefore, Selenium IDE, too) and one of the reasons why Selenium 2 (WebDriver) was developed. If you want to catch `onload` JS alerts, you need [to use WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#popup-dialogs) [alert handling](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html).

That said, you can use [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) or [`selenium.keyPressNative()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#keyPressNative%28java.lang.String%29) to fill in any text and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and confirm the dialog blindly. It's not the cleanest way, but it could work. You won't be able to get the `alert` message, however.

`Robot` has all the useful keys mapped to constants, so that will be easy. With `keyPressNative()`, you want to use `10` as value for pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `27` for <kbd>Esc</kbd> since it works with [ASCII codes](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using chooseOkOnNextConfirmation you can do that.

```
selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation();  // prepares Selenium to handle next alert
selenium.click(locator);
String alertText = selenium.getAlert(); // verifies that alert was shown
assertEquals("This is a popup window", alertText);
```

For more information, go through this link [link](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Unless you use something that can control the browser (e.g. selenium).

If you do use selenium, have a look at [Click in OK button inside an Alert (Selenium IDE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348937/click-in-ok-button-inside-an-alert-selenium-ide)

Comment: I do us selenium RC and looked at that question but nothing worked. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you can simulate a keypress of the space bar or enter key, then that will dismiss the alert. However you'd better be doing this from outside whatever makes the alert show up in the first place, since they tend to be blocking.

If this is JavaScript, you may be better off using `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation(); is working for me in Selenium RC.

We have to comment the code for Alert OK button then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->chooseOkOnNextConfirmation();
$this->click('locator');
$this->getConfirmation();
```

The above process worked for me using Selenium RC with PHPUnit

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

you want to try this code in show alert and ok and cancel button

```
let sharephotoAction = UIAlertController.init(title: "Confirm Ticket", message:"Please Collect Your Ticket Before 1 Hours Ago in Location", preferredStyle: .alert )
        sharephotoAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in

            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.Save), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        }))
        sharephotoAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancle", style: .default, handler:nil))

        self.present(sharephotoAction, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use GSEvent.h for handling any type of keypress events, It is availble in GraphicsServices framework, It is private framewrk(so, you are not able submit it on appstore).