# automate javascript clicks within code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, browser, browser-extension

I want to code some script (language is not a problem), which will open a site in webbrowser or webbrowser control. but the problem I am facing is that some sites have javascript alerts/confirm (ok/cancel) buttons appear during start or if some error occurs. I don't want the user to click these buttons manually, but write some code which clicks these messages. is there any way to do so?

EDIT:
I have requirement from a client to create a new desktop application or plugin for browser which will send OK message for all confirm or alerts. Please note that I don't have access to code for these websites user want to visit. Hope this will make it more clear.

Comment: I think really you would be looking at some sort of automated UI tool for this.

Comment: It will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749959/how-can-i-press-the-alert-ok-button-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Depends what are your exact requirements you could check something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), which is a free and powerful UI automation tool. 
If you can be bound to exactly one browser, you could maybe take advantage of augmented browsing tools like [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

Although I don't know if this satisfies your requirements - I have a feeling that you require this for mobile, since you are mentioning webbrowser control. But I hope it's a good start point for figuring it out further.