# jquery: when an confirm is dynamically written can you return the true function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, dynamic-html

A php page has a jquery interface.
an on submit button dynamically writes an alert.
the confirm box is of the style : return confirm.

in other words there is a script on the page that does something like this:

confirm (okay  cancel );

I need a way of listening for when the alert has been dynamically written so I can confirm it dynamically.
any ideas?

is there an event listener for 'confirm'?

---

```html
    <html>
       <head>   
<script>           
                function getConfirmation() {
                   var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
                   if( retVal == true ) {
                      document.write ("User wants to continue!");
                      return true;
                   } else {
                      document.write ("User does not want to continue!");
                      return false;
                   }
                }
           
          </script>     
       
       </head>
       
       <body>
          <p>Click the following button to see the result: </p>      
          <form>
             <input type = "button" value = "Click Me" onclick = "getConfirmation();" />
          </form>      
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is this your code that triggers the alert? Explain your use case in more detail. There is no event emitted by an alert built in but possibly ways of handling your situation depending on use case

Comment: No : the submit button prior to this triggers the alert. however I need to dynamically click [okay] when the alert pops up. @charlietfl

Comment: Now that it's related to a form submit the issue gets even more complex depending on what happens in the submit handlerwhat you are trying to accomplish  and you really need to explain more and show a [mcve]

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I press the alert ok button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749959/how-can-i-press-the-alert-ok-button-programmatically)

Comment: @Davide Vitali : that answer has to do with Selenium IDE which is now deprecated in any case. SO no, not a duplicate.

Comment: An `alert()` is not the same as a `confirm()` - and no, you can't access either of these via javascript as alert/confirm halt the javascript thread while they are displayed and javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: Really just back to this being an XY Problem and you haven't provided a detailed explanation of use case and what you need to accompish at a higher level

Comment: Please explain what you want to happen. You don't want the user to see or answer to the `confirm` dialog? Then why do you have it in the first place? Just don't trigger it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.confirm = function() { }` to intercept the `confirm` command.

Returning `true` would be the same as clicking the "ok" button.

```js
window.confirm = function() { return true; }

if (window.confirm("Delete everything?") == true)
{
    alert("Deleting all your files as you confirmed")
}
```